# npm run build:prod, hatası " TS2307: Cannot find module" angular ng toolkit universal

Tags: angular, npm

I wanted to edit the site for seo.
I have a package named `ng toolkit universal` which I'm trying to use.

I installed it as described on this link, *

> I installed this package using `ng add @ ng-toolkit / universal --http false`

After running `npm run build: prod`

I got the following errors-

> ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(169,7): Error during template compile
>   of 'AppModule'   Could not resolve
>   src/shared/confirm-equal-validator.directive relative to [object
>   Object].. src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-videos.component.ts(3,31):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/router.service'.
>   src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-videos.component.ts(5,27): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/Twchannel'.
>   src/app/admin/login/login.component.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'src/app/app_classes/globalvariable'.
>   src/app/admin/login/login.component.ts(3,29): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'src/app/services/auth.service'.
>   src/app/admin/login/login.component.ts(4,27): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'src/app/models/loginUser'.
>   src/app/home/instagram/instagram.component.ts(2,34): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'src/app/services/instagram.service'.
>   src/app/home/instagram/instagram.component.ts(3,33): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'src/app/models/instagramPhotos'.
>   src/app/home/instagram/instagram.component.ts(5,30): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'src/app/app.component'.
>   src/app/home/instagram/instagram.component.ts(6,30): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'src/app/nav/nav.component'.
>   src/app/admin/streams-ctrl/streams-ctrl.component.ts(2,32): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/streams.service'.
>   src/app/admin/streams-ctrl/streams-ctrl.component.ts(3,25): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/streams'.
>   src/app/admin/videos-ctrl/videos-ctrl.component.ts(2,24): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/videos'.
>   src/app/admin/videos-ctrl/videos-ctrl.component.ts(3,31): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/videos.service'.
>   src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-details/stream-details.component.ts(3,32):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/streams.service'.
>   src/app/home/stream-videos/stream-details/stream-details.component.ts(4,25):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/streams'.
>   src/app/admin/modal/modal.component.ts(10,37): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module 'src/app/models/achievementsAddEdit'.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! unchained@0.0.0
>   build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod && ng run
>   Unchained:server:production` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the unchained@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Zafer.Kirik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-24T12_47_29_290Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! unchained@0.0.0
>   build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run
>   compile:server` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   unchained@0.0.0 build:ssr script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Zafer.Kirik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-24T12_47_29_333Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! unchained@0.0.0
>   build:prod: `npm run build:ssr` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm
>   ERR! Failed at the unchained@0.0.0 build:prod script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Zafer.Kirik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-24T12_47_29_374Z-debug.log
>   PS D:\UnchainedRepoClone\unchained 25032019\unchained-9> node -v
>   v11.14.0 PS D:\UnchainedRepoClone\unchained 25032019\unchained-9>
>   angular -v angular : The term 'angular' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try ag ain. At line:1 char:1
>   + angular -v
>   + ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (angular:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

My AppModule.ts:

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { AnimateComponent } from './animate/animate.component';
    import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { SliderComponent } from './home/slider/slider.component';
    import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    import { TeamsComponent } from './teams/teams.component';
    import { StreamVideosComponent } from './home/stream-videos/stream-videos.component';
    import { NewsComponent } from './home/news/news.component';
    import { CalendarMinComponent } from './home/news/calendar-min/calendar-min.component';
    import { FixtureComponent } from './fixture/fixture.component';
    import { OurTeamsComponent } from './home/our-teams/our-teams.component';
    import { InstagramComponent } from './home/instagram/instagram.component';

    import { InstagramService } from './services/instagram.service';
    import { GalleryComponent } from './gallery/gallery.component';
    import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
    import { PartnersComponent } from './partners/partners.component';
    import { StreamsComponent } from './streams/streams.component';
    import { VideoComponent } from './video/video.component';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './admin/login/login.component';
    import { OthernavComponent } from './othernav/othernav.component';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { LoginGuard } from './app_classes/login.guard';
    import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
    import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
    import { LeftsidebarComponent } from './admin/leftsidebar/leftsidebar.component';
    import { StreamsCtrlComponent } from './admin/streams-ctrl/streams-ctrl.component';
    import { SafePipe } from './pipe/safe.pipe';
    import { VideosCtrlComponent } from './admin/videos-ctrl/videos-ctrl.component';
    import { StreamDetailsComponent } from './home/stream-videos/stream-details/stream-details.component';
    import { IconControlPipe } from './pipe/iconControl.pipe';
    import { AchievementsComponent } from './achievements/achievements.component';
    import { AchievementsCtrlComponent } from './admin/achievements-ctrl/achievements-ctrl.component';
    import { AchievementsSearchPipe } from './pipe/AchievementsSearch.pipe';
    import { AchievementsFilterByDatePipe } from './pipe/achievementsFilterByDate.pipe';
    import { AchievementsFilterByPrizePipe } from './pipe/achievementsFilterByPrize.pipe';
    import { ModalComponent } from './admin/modal/modal.component';

       import {
       MatButtonModule,
       MatCardModule,
       MatDialogModule,
       MatIconModule, 
       MatMenuModule,
       MatToolbarModule,
       MatAutocompleteModule,
       MatBadgeModule,
       MatBottomSheetModule,
       MatButtonToggleModule,
       MatCheckboxModule,
       MatChipsModule,
       MatStepperModule,
       MatDatepickerModule,
       MatDividerModule,
       MatExpansionModule,
       MatGridListModule,
       MatInputModule,
       MatListModule,
       MatNativeDateModule,
       MatPaginatorModule,
       MatProgressBarModule,
       MatProgressSpinnerModule,
       MatRadioModule,
       MatRippleModule,
       MatSelectModule,
       MatSidenavModule,
       MatSliderModule,
       MatSlideToggleModule,
       MatSnackBarModule,
       MatSortModule,
       MatTableModule,
       MatTabsModule,
       MatTooltipModule,
       MatTreeModule,
    } from '@angular/material';
    import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
    import { AchievementsFilterByGamePipe } from './pipe/achievementsFilterByGame.pipe';
    import { IntToactivepassivePipe } from './pipe/intToactivepassive.pipe';
    import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from './pipe/sanitizeHtml.pipe';
    import { StreamsHomeComponent } from './home/stream-videos/streamsHome/streamsHome.component';
    import { VideosHomeComponent } from './home/stream-videos/videosHome/videosHome.component';
    import { VideoDetailsComponent } from './home/stream-videos/video-details/video-details.component';
    import { VideoOrderByDescPipe } from './pipe/videoOrderByDesc.pipe';
    import { RouterLinkReplacePipe } from './pipe/routerLinkReplace.pipe';
    import { RouterLinkUnReplacePipe } from './pipe/RouterLinkUnReplace.pipe';
    import { TwitchchannelsCtrlComponent } from './admin/twitchchannels-ctrl/twitchchannels-ctrl.component';
    import { ModalfortwitchctrlComponent } from './admin/twitchchannels-ctrl/modalfortwitchctrl/modalfortwitchctrl.component';
    import { TwchannelsGameIdToNameConvertPipe } from './pipe/twchannelsGameIdToNameConvert.pipe';
    import { TwchannelsPlayerIdToNameConvertPipe } from './pipe/twchannelsPlayerIdToNameConvert.pipe';
    import { TwhannelsSearchByUserNamePipe } from './pipe/twhannelsSearchByUserName.pipe';
    import { TwchannelsSearchByIdPipe } from './pipe/twchannelsSearchById.pipe';
    import { UsersCtrlComponent } from './admin/users-ctrl/users-ctrl.component';
    import { ModalforusersctrlComponent } from './admin/users-ctrl/modalforusersctrl/modalforusersctrl.component';
    import { ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective } from 'src/shared/confirm-equal-validator.directive';
    import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
    import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
    import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
    import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
    import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
    import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
    import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

    @NgModule({
       declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          HomeComponent,
          SliderComponent,
          NavComponent,
          TeamsComponent,
          TeamsComponent,
          StreamVideosComponent,
          NewsComponent,
          AnimateComponent,
          CalendarMinComponent,
          FixtureComponent,
          OurTeamsComponent,
          GalleryComponent,
          InstagramComponent,
          FooterComponent,
          PartnersComponent,
          StreamsComponent,
          VideoComponent,
          AdminComponent,
          LoginComponent,
          OthernavComponent,
          LeftsidebarComponent,
          StreamsCtrlComponent,
          VideosCtrlComponent,
          StreamDetailsComponent,
          AchievementsComponent,
          AchievementsCtrlComponent,
          ModalComponent,
          StreamsHomeComponent,
          VideosHomeComponent,
          VideoDetailsComponent,
          TwitchchannelsCtrlComponent,
          ModalfortwitchctrlComponent,
          UsersCtrlComponent,
          ModalforusersctrlComponent,
          SafePipe,
          IconControlPipe,
          AchievementsSearchPipe,
          AchievementsFilterByDatePipe,
          AchievementsFilterByPrizePipe,
          AchievementsFilterByGamePipe,
          IntToactivepassivePipe,
          SanitizeHtmlPipe,
          VideoOrderByDescPipe,
          RouterLinkReplacePipe,
          RouterLinkUnReplacePipe,
          TwchannelsGameIdToNameConvertPipe,
          TwchannelsPlayerIdToNameConvertPipe,
          TwhannelsSearchByUserNamePipe,
          TwchannelsSearchByIdPipe,


          ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective
       ],
       imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          HttpClientModule,
          AppRoutingModule,
          NgbModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
          FormsModule,
          MatToolbarModule,
          MatCardModule,
          MatMenuModule,
          MatIconModule,
          MatButtonModule,
          MatDialogModule,
          FileUploadModule,
          MatAutocompleteModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          A11yModule,
          CdkStepperModule,
          CdkTableModule,
          CdkTreeModule,
          DragDropModule,
          MatAutocompleteModule,
          MatBadgeModule,
          MatBottomSheetModule,
          MatButtonModule,
          MatButtonToggleModule,
          MatCardModule,
          MatCheckboxModule,
          MatChipsModule,
          MatStepperModule,
          MatDatepickerModule,
          MatDialogModule,
          MatDividerModule,
          MatExpansionModule,
          MatGridListModule,
          MatIconModule,
          MatInputModule,
          MatListModule,
          MatMenuModule,
          MatNativeDateModule,
          MatPaginatorModule,
          MatProgressBarModule,
          MatProgressSpinnerModule,
          MatRadioModule,
          MatRippleModule,
          MatSelectModule,
          MatSidenavModule,
          MatSliderModule,
          MatSlideToggleModule,
          MatSnackBarModule,
          MatSortModule,
          MatTableModule,
          MatTabsModule,
          MatToolbarModule,
          MatTooltipModule,
          MatTreeModule,
          PortalModule,
          ScrollingModule
       ],
       exports: [
          A11yModule,
          CdkStepperModule,
          CdkTableModule,
          CdkTreeModule,
          DragDropModule,
          MatAutocompleteModule,
          MatBadgeModule,
          MatBottomSheetModule,
          MatButtonModule,
          MatButtonToggleModule,
          MatCardModule,
          MatCheckboxModule,
          MatChipsModule,
          MatStepperModule,
          MatDatepickerModule,
          MatDialogModule,
          MatDividerModule,
          MatExpansionModule,
          MatGridListModule,
          MatIconModule,
          MatInputModule,
          MatListModule,
          MatMenuModule,
          MatNativeDateModule,
          MatPaginatorModule,
          MatProgressBarModule,
          MatProgressSpinnerModule,
          MatRadioModule,
          MatRippleModule,
          MatSelectModule,
          MatSidenavModule,
          MatSliderModule,
          MatSlideToggleModule,
          MatSnackBarModule,
          MatSortModule,
          MatTableModule,
          MatTabsModule,
          MatToolbarModule,
          MatTooltipModule,
          MatTreeModule,
          PortalModule,
          ScrollingModule,

       ],
       providers: [
          InstagramService,
          LoginGuard,
          AuthService
       ],
       bootstrap: [
          AppComponent
       ],
       entryComponents: [ModalComponent, ModalfortwitchctrlComponent, ModalforusersctrlComponent]
    })

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't done the command: *npm install* which will download and install all the needed modules and dependencies. 
(according to the log, modules are missed)

Comment: can I ask you to extend the question by providing the source of : src\app\app.module.ts(169,7) file? and maybe some idea about modules/files structure (it seems the project is quite big and has many dependencies)

Comment: try to move directives that are missed from src/shared into app/shared and update import link in the App.module